# Change tinymce toolbar buttons after initilised with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I need to change the toolbar buttons after the instance has loaded.  The below example should change the buttons to only show save and new document, however it doesn't.

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Hvcaab

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true
});

$(function(){
    $('#testbutt').click(function(e){        
        console.log($('#testing').tinymce().theme.settings.theme_advanced_buttons1);
        $('#testing').tinymce().theme.settings.theme_advanced_buttons1 = "save,newdocument";
        console.log($('#testing').tinymce().theme.settings.theme_advanced_buttons1);
        $('#testing').tinymce().execCommand("mceRepaint");
        $('#testing').tinymce().render();
    });
})

</script>
<input type="button" id="testbutt" value="test">
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
        <textarea name="content" id="testing">
        </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: looks like you will have to sut down that tinymce editor instance and reinit it new with a new button config

Comment: @Thariama that's what I figured but what a waste of memory and resources!

Comment: the only other option would be to hide those buttons from the user

Comment: sadly its to do with resizing the window, showing the toolbars on a single line instead of 2.  I have a solution........ kind of....... fire an event after the window has resized to reload it...... blah